# Compare multiple boolean values

Tags: android, boolean-logic

i have three boolean value returning from the method , i want to check condition  like this :First It will check all the three boolean value

Scenario 1: if locationMatch, matchCapacity, filterMatchStatus then statement return true value.

Scenario 2: if locationMatch, matchCapacity, filterMatchStatus if any boolean is false then it return false value

I tried like this but , it is returning true if any boolean value is true

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter){

            boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
            boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
            boolean filterMatchStatus = filterMatchesStatus(filter);
            if (locationMatch) {
                return true;
            }
            if (matchCapacity) {
                return true;
            }
            if (filterMatchStatus) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: use this 
`if (locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus){
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}`

Comment: Remove all the if conditions and change your return statement to `return (locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code try this.

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter) {

    boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
    boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
    boolean filterMatchStatus = filterMatchesStatus(filter);

    return locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of `if(..)` here?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code. Use '&' Operator in your case, because '&' will return true, if expression are satisfying the given conditions, otherwise result will be false

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter){
            boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
            boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
            boolean filterMatchStatus = filterMatchesStatus(filter);
        return locationMatch && matchCapacity  && filterMatchStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `if` conditions and return the following from your method

```
 return (locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answers, but in a shorter form (and it has a single exit point!):

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter)
{
    boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
    boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
    boolean filterMatchStatus = filterMatchesStatus(filter);
    return (locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter){

        boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
        boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
        boolean filterMatchStatus = filterMatchesStatus(filter);

        return locationMatch && matchCapacity && filterMatchStatus;
    }
```

code minimized. Thank you to @Deepak . Basically you are saying here that only returns true if all 3 variables are true. if one is false, statement returns false (Boolean algebra)

Comment: what is the use of `if(..)` here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public boolean matchFilter(FilterTruck filter){
    return filterMatchesLocation(filter) && filterMatchesCapacity(filter) && filterMatchesStatus(filter);
}
```