# How to fix multiple boolean values being printed

Tags: python-3.x

Right now I'm led to believe that my function is incorrect since I am getting more than 1 boolean output.

```
listOstrings = ['cat in the hat','michael meyers','mercury.','austin powers','hi']


def StringLength(searchInteger, listOstrings):

'return Boolean value if the strings are shorter/longer than the first argument'

for i in listOstrings:
    if len(i) < searchInteger:
        print(False)

    else:
        print(True)
```

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing `print` with `return`. They are two *completely* different things; the fact that the REPL prints the return value of a function call blurs the distinction, though.

Comment: Using `print` instead of `return` is just your *first* problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare multiple boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036959/compare-multiple-boolean-values)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to *print* `True` or `False` for each item; you want to create a single Boolean over the course of iterating over the loop. Or more simply, you can return `False` as soon as you find one element that fails the test, returning `True` only if you make it through the entire loop without returning.

```
def checkStringLength(searchInteger, lstStrings):
    'return Boolean value if the strings are shorter/longer than the first argument'
    for i in lstStrings:
        if len(i) < searchInteger:
            return False
    return True
```

This is more naturally written using the `all` function:

```
def checkStringLength(searchInteger, lstStrings):
    return all(len(i) >= searchInteger for i in lstStrings)
```

Comment: the **all** function is exactly what I was missing. I assume asking for a return of True/False values is redundant? Or just not best practice? New to learning python so I'm very appreciative of your help :)

Comment: `all` is just a little more descriptive; it does *what* you want without having to write *how* to do it. The first version just gives you more opportunities to make an error in the logic, while `all` already encapsulates the correct logic; you just have to use the right comparison, and it's easier to do that given that the call to `all` *almost* reads like an English sentence.